# How to pass values as param value via URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, c#-4.0

On my site (www.mysite.com) I have checkout which redirects to outside site (www.checkoutsite.com), then after payment it sends back POST request to my site. In url I pass all needed information for checkout, but I need also pass my own data, for that it has "UserData" url param

so, my site redirects user to url: http://checkoutsite.com/payment/?AppLogin=MyLogin&AppPass=MyPass&UserData=[here should be my data]

I need to pass different key=value values in "UserData" param, then read on my side.

What is the best way to do it in ASP.NET, I mean how to pack key=value values into one string?

Comment: `payment` and `AppLogin=MyLogin&AppPass=MyPass` in the same url. I would like to know which site this is :)

Comment: The "best" way would seem to be "any other way at all" or just put your credit card, bank and personal details in this post so it is "over" with less work.

Comment: To L.B, it's just an example, actually there is TicketId

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I created Dictionary and serialize/deserialize it exactly like described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx

it resolves a problem.

Comment: And what is the relation with the link you posted and your question? Your title is `How to pass values as param value via URL` and you found a json solution.

Comment: Can't help you that you don't understand. I serialize my data into one string like described in the post i linked and passed that serialized string as a value of param in url &UserData=[here should be my data - (here is serialized string)], when I got that param next time on the server I deserialize that string and read all values I need. Thanks